# How to create an adjacency matrix from data set

Tags: c#, visual-studio, graph

I have a 2 dimensional list that includes student numbers where each row represents a different lecture. I want to find out if a student takes more than one lecture and if so turn it into an adjacency matrix.

List look like this:

```
 18011011   18011024   18011055
 18011022   18011024   18011034
 18011011   18011023   18011045   18011100
```

And matrix should be like this:

```
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 0
```

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Yollar.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Yollar[i].Count; j++)
    {
        for (int k = i + 1; k < Yollar.Count; k++)
        {
            for (int p = 0; p < Yollar[k].Count; p++)
            {
                if (Yollar[i][j] == Yollar[k][p])
                {
                    AdjancencyMatrix[i, p] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Forget to write WH question part :D (rewrite the title btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < Yollar.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < Yollar[i].Count; j++)
    {
        for (int k =i +1; k < Yollar.Count; k++)
        {
            for(int p = 0; p < Yollar[k].Count; p++)
            {
                if (Yollar[i][j] == Yollar[k][p])
                {
                    AdjancencyMatrix[i, k] = 1;
                    AdjancencyMatrix[k, i] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I figured out. I only need lecture indexes so if you use only row indexes and changed the AdjacencyMatrix indexes and problem solved